# Insert database mysql get issue

Tags: java, mysql, database

i got issue when i go to Insert value to DB (do nothing).
before that i do select table to get last id, and it worked.
 Here's my Code:

```
IDBManager dbManager = getParentExtension().getParentZone().getDBManager();
    Connection connection = null;   

    int idRoom = params.getInt("idRoom");
    String betsmall = params.getUtfString("betsmall");
    int Uid  = params.getInt("recid");

    try{
        connection = dbManager.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT id_game from detail_game ORDER BY id_game DESC LIMIT 1");

        ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery();
        if (!res.first())
        {
            trace("bla bla");
        }

        int id = res.getInt("id_game");
       trace (id);
    //  **till here there is no problem, i can get id from select query

      PreparedStatement stmts = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO detil_bet (id_user, id_room, id_bet, bettype) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ? ");
      stmts.setInt(1, Uid);
      stmts.setInt(2, idRoom);
      stmts.setInt(3, id);
      stmts.setString(4, betsmall);
      stmts.executeUpdate();

    }
}
```

Here's the problem, insert do nothing.

Comment: You're missing `)` in values part.

Comment: In the case there is a `)` missing you should get an exception?!

Answer (score 1):

```
PreparedStatement stmts = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO detil_bet (id_user, id_room, id_bet, bettype) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ? ");
```

Looks like you need some end parentheses in "VALUES".

A catch block to print stack trace would have told you the issue here as well. I'm not the best SQL guy, I always use [this](https://www.piliapp.com/mysql-syntax-check/) to check my SQL syntax as well to double check if I've done everything right.

Answer (score 0):

your connection seems not auto commit. Try to add

```
stmts.commit();
```

after "stmts.executeUpdate();".